# Getting 403 error and "n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send" when sending a post request using Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am trying to send a simple `ajax` request while using `node.js`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Earth" }
})
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/ 403 (Forbidden)jquery-2.1.3.min.js:4      
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.sendjquery-2.1.3.min.js:4 
n.extend.ajaxVM475:2 (anonymous function)VM465:777 
InjectedScript._evaluateOnVM465:710 
InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrapVM465:626 InjectedScript.evaluate
```

I have a controller set up that handles other types of POST requests, but for some reason it won't handle this one.

I thought that perhaps it was occuring because I was running the code in the console, but when I did the following I got the same error message:

```
$(document).on('click',function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: { name: "John", location: "Earth" }
  })
});
```

ALSO, when I use `type:"GET"` it works no problem. **I am assuming it is some sort of cross site scripting error**, but I'm not scripting cross site? What do I need to do to send this `POST` request?

UPDATE, I am using the `hackathon starter` package:
https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter#why-do-i-get-403-error-forbidden-when-submitting-a-form
Which states the following:

*"You need to add the following hidden input element to your form. This has been added in the pull request #40 as part of the CSRF protection.
input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)*

*Note: It is now possible to whitelist certain URLs. In other words you can specify a list of routes that should bypass CSRF verification check.*

*Note 2: To whitelist dynamic URLs use regular expression tests inside the CSRF middleware to see if req.originalUrl matches your desired pattern."*

Comment: That seems like a cross origin problem

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a cross origin problem, since the request is being sent FROM `localhost:3000/` TO `localhost:3000/`

Comment: check your console and see what the request is like

Comment: It says Error: `CSRF token mismatch...at csrf  lusca/lib/csrf`

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to this problem:

1) Inside of `app.js` change the line `csrf: true` to `csrf: false`, as in the following:

```
app.use(lusca({
  csrf: false,
  xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  xssProtection: true
}));
```

2) Delete the `lusca` module and delete all of the following references to it inside of `app.js`:

```
var lusca = require('lusca');

app.use(lusca({
  csrf: false,
  xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
  xssProtection: true
}));
```